# MVC Валидация данных. Свойство [Require]

Tags: asp.net, require, mvc, валидация

**Добрый день.
есть небольшая модель:**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Max
{

    public class ContactViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name can't exceeds 50 chars.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Email can't exceeds 50 chars.")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please write you message")]
        [Display(Name = "Your Message")]
        public string MessageText { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Валидация срабатывает только на запрос "@" в мэйле, НЕ срабатывает запрос о введении Имени и Текста. Подскажите что я делаю не правильно !
Представление выглядит следующим образом :**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)<text>:* </text>
        <br />
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
        <br />
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)<text>:* </text>
        <br />
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
        <br />
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MessageText)<text>:* </text>
        <br />
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.MessageText)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MessageText)

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />

            <span style="color: #00ff21">
                @ViewBag.MessageSend
            </span>
        </p>

 }
```

Comment: Код экшена в контроллере покажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Даже если пришла пустая строка, то это считается корректными данными и require молчит. Подозреваю, что дело в этом, если да, то проверяйте длину.

Comment: @Alexey123 Это было бы так, если бы атрибут required был указан со свойством [AllowEmptyStrings][1]:

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
Я все еще настаиваю на коде контроллера! :)


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.allowemptystrings(v=vs.100).aspx